# jQuery toggle next element from $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a button with toggles a div element on click.
When i click the button nothing happens on my website. I think there is a problem with the $(this) selector, but i cannot guess why.
The Code is working on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/06j3kug8/

**HTML**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary flip">Spoiler</a>
<div class="spoiler">test</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.spoiler { display:none }
```

**Script in footer**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(function($){

    $(".flip").on("click",function(){
       $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });


 });
 </script>
```

Comment: share your console error

Comment: `TypeError: jQuery(...) is not a function` -- this error occurs when you didn't include jQuery in your page. You should check again.

Comment: only possible reason is that you have not included jquery file

Comment: the header section includes jquery.js and jquery-migrate.min.js but in the last 1.x versions. After the Scripts were included the custom js is included

Answer (score 0):

I think you call your `jquery.js` in bottom please take it on top and before your jquery custom code like below:-

Its working fine:-

The Code is working on jsfiddle because of there is already called jquery.js on top & before your custom jquery code.

```js
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(function($){

    $(".flip").on("click",function(){
       $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });


 });
```

```css
.spoiler { display:none }
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-primary flip">Spoiler</a>
<div class="spoiler">test</div>
```